# How to use DecimalFormat to hide trailing zero in numbers "with decimals" only

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm using DecimalFormat to remove trailing zeros from my outputs using the pattern `#.#`
this produces outputs like

> 12.5 --> 12.5
>
> 12 --> 12

however I need to make it produce

> 12.5 --> 12.5
>
> 12 --> 12.0

How can this happen ?

Comment: Show how are your formatting your string for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use #.0 to show the digit. # treat 0 as absent.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 6):

The Javadoc for `DecimalFormat` says that the `0` symbol represents a digit, while `#` will remove the zero if it is leading or trailing. For example:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DecimalFormat zeroes = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
    DecimalFormat hashes = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

    System.out.println(zeroes.format(12.0)); // 12.0
    System.out.println(zeroes.format(12.5)); // 12.5
    System.out.println(hashes.format(12.0)); // 12
    System.out.println(hashes.format(12.5)); // 12.5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set max and min precision by:

```
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(maxPrecision);
decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(minPrecision);
```